# Linking with native SO file present in included library project of Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I am working on a project in which it has dependency on another library project. Library project has both java files and native SO files.

Accessing JAVA source files (APIs) from the Android project java source doesn't have any problem. But, my native code is dependent on native SO files present in the included library project of android as well.

```
Library Project         Android Project
---------------         ---------------
src/Java files    <--   Java files
libs/.so files    <--   libs/.so files
```

.so files are part of the included library project. How can my current Android project native code try to use .so files of the included library project. Currently I am getting **linking error of undefined reference** to all the functions which are part of the library/libs/.so files.

Please let me know if any one has faced/resolved similar type of issue.

Comment: Why don't you post your Android.mk files, and post the actual link error message, verbatim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have both projects imported into your Eclipse. But `ndk-build` knows nothing about Eclipse. If the library comes with its own **.mk** file that defines `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY`, it would be even better. One such example is [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#native-c) which includes **sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk** file.

But you can simply add path to the **.so** files to your **Android.mk**, e.g. put the following lines in the end of your file:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:=LibraryProjectSO
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=/LibraryProject/libs/library.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Now you can add **LibraryProjectSO** to the list of **LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES**.